# My listView is lagging so much

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-edittext, lag

I have a MainActivity, CustomListAdapter, customlistItem.xml, mainlayout.xml.

My ListView contains an editable EditText.

i'm trying for

1. if text in editText is changed,
2. database update, listView(listItem) update.

**customListAdapter :**

```
public class subMyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

Context context;
LayoutInflater Inflater;
ArrayList<subMyItem> arraySrc;
int layout;
EditText tvItem;
UserHolder holder;
myDBHelper myHelper;
public subMyListAdapter(Context context, int layout, ArrayList<subMyItem> arraySrc, myDBHelper myHelper)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.layout = layout;
    this.arraySrc = arraySrc;
    Inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    myHelper = this.myHelper;
}


public int getCount()
{
    return arraySrc.size();
}

public String getItem(int position)
{
    return arraySrc.get(position).list;
}

public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return position;
}



public View getView(final int position, View conv, ViewGroup parent)
{
    holder = null;

     if (conv == null) 
     {
       LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
       conv = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
       holder = new UserHolder();
       holder.tvItem = (EditText)conv.findViewById(R.id.tvItem);
       conv.setTag(holder);
     }
     else 
     {
       holder = (UserHolder) conv.getTag();
     }

     if(holder == null)
     {
       holder = new UserHolder();
       holder.tvItem = (EditText)conv.findViewById(R.id.tvItem);
       conv.setTag(holder);
     }

     subMyItem user = arraySrc.get(position);
     holder.tvItem.setOnTouchListener(test);
     holder.tvItem.setTag(position);
     conv.setOnTouchListener(test);

    TextView count = (TextView)conv.findViewById(R.id.tvItemCount);
    count.setText(String.valueOf(arraySrc.size()));
    FrameLayout bg = (FrameLayout)conv.findViewById(R.id.bg);


    EditText tvItem = (EditText) conv.findViewById(R.id.tvItem);
    user = arraySrc.get(position);
    if(!tvItem.getText().toString().equals(user.list))
      tvItem.setText(user.list);
    tvItem.setTag(position);

    TextWatchert at = new TextWatchert();
    at.sqlId=user.id;
    at.position=position;

    tvItem.addTextChangedListener(at);
    return conv;
}

class TextWatchert implements TextWatcher
{
    int sqlId;
    int position;

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(openPositon != position)return;

        myHelper = new myDBHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = myHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        String update = "UPDATE clearTBL SET list='" + tvItem.getText().toString()+ "' WHERE id=" + sqlId + ";";
        try
        {
        sqlDB.execSQL(update);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

        sqlDB.close();
        myListActivity.arrItem.get(position).list = s.toString();
    }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {

    }

}

int openPositon = -1;

View.OnTouchListener test=  new View.OnTouchListener() 
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        if (view instanceof EditText) 
        {
            tvItem = (EditText) view;
            tvItem.setFocusable(true);
            tvItem.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            try
            {
                openPositon = Integer.parseInt(tvItem.getTag().toString()); 
            }
            catch
            (Exception e)
            {}

        } else 
        {
            hideSoftKeyboard();
            view.requestFocus();
            UserHolder holder = (UserHolder) view.getTag();
            holder.tvItem.clearFocus();
            holder.tvItem.setMovementMethod(null);
            holder.tvItem.setFocusable(false);
            holder.tvItem.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
            openPositon=-1;
        }
    return false;
    }
};
public void hideSoftKeyboard()
{
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(((Activity)context).getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
 static class UserHolder 
 {
      EditText tvItem;
     }
```

}

My code is working fine.But it's too slow, lag so so much when I'm trying to edit.
scrolling, touch is ok. Just editing is takes much time.

I think there is a problem with `addTextChangedListener` code.

How Can I Reduce Lag?

**Edit**

ok, new code is

```
View.OnTouchListener test=  new View.OnTouchListener() 
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        if (view instanceof EditText) 
        {
             tVibrator = (Vibrator)context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
             tVibrator.vibrate(50);
            tvItem = (EditText) view;
            tvItem.setFocusable(true);
            tvItem.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            try
            {
                openPositon = Integer.parseInt(tvItem.getTag().toString()); 
            }
            catch
            (Exception e)
            {}

        } else 
        {
            hideSoftKeyboard();
            view.requestFocus();
            UserHolder holder = (UserHolder) view.getTag();
            holder.tvItem.clearFocus();
            holder.tvItem.setMovementMethod(null);
            holder.tvItem.setFocusable(false);
            holder.tvItem.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
            openPositon=-1;

            try
            {
                sPosition = tvItem.getTag().toString(); 
            }
            catch
            (Exception e)
            {}
            if(sPosition!=null)
            {
                int pos = Integer.parseInt(sPosition);
                myHelper = new myDBHelper(context);
                SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = myHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                subMyItem user = arraySrc.get(pos);
                int a = user.id;
                String update = "UPDATE clearTBL SET list='" + tvItem.getText().toString()+ "' WHERE id=" + a + ";";
                try
                {
                    sqlDB.execSQL(update);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                sqlDB.close();

                myListActivity.arrItem.get(pos).list = tvItem.toString();
            }
        }
    return false;
    }
};
```

Now all code is works fine. Thank you everybody!

Comment: The fact that you're executing a SQL query on every text change might have something to do with it.

Comment: maybe you should set the db update in async task.

Comment: its but oblivious that your list is tooo much slow because have executed SQL query in getview and mind it that for each row getview call and when you implement ontextchnage listener meanse every text you are calling SQL and more is you close DB after query and also keep in mind opening and closing DB is too much hard work for OS  so change your coding pattern :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only update the database after you have finished editing the text field. At the moment you are updating it every time you make a text change. Remove the `TextWatcher` and move your SQL somewhere that you can trigger it manually after you are satisfied with the edit.